# How can I setup double-sided printing for the Xerox 7400?

Tags: printer

How can I setup double-sided printing for the Xerox 7400?

Comment: This maybe better on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

You can see step-by-step instructions [here](http://www.office.xerox.com/userdoc/P7400/7400_Web/videos/duplex_unit.html).